# How to stop and start all threads at a certain point with semaphores? java

Tags: java, semaphore

Trying to replace a monitor with semaphores. The idea is to wait threads until they have all reached this function.

Here is the monitor:

```
public void checkThreadsAreToChangeColor() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (waitingThreads <= 1) { // Threads are going
                waitingThreads++;
                try {
                    System.out.println(this.id + " sleeping");
                    lock.wait();
                    return;
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            lock.notifyAll(); // Last thread to change color
            waitingThreads = 0;
            limit = 99999999;
            startTimeOnType = System.currentTimeMillis();;
        }
    }
```

For more detail there are and always will be 3 threads if that helps.

Using pveentjer's code i managed to solve my problem.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: The question would be how do you stop threads until all threads have have reached a location using semaphores. Edited my title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a CyclicBarrier.

So with a sempahore you will wait once the counter has reached zero.

With a CyclicBarrier a group of thread wait till the last thread of the group has completed.

So the CyclicBarrier is a more appropriate solution for your problem.

[edit] I have updated my answer because I misinterpreted the question. There is not a thread waiting for a bunch of threads to reach a common point, but a group of threads need to wait for each thread to reach this common point.

[edit2] I have added a CyclicBarrier implementation based on Semaphores.

```
class CyclicBarrier{
   private final Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
   private final Semaphore waiters = new Semaphore();
   private final int parties;
   private int completed_parties;
   
   public CyclicBarrier(int parties){
      this.parties = parties;
   }
   
   public void await() throws InterruptedException {
       boolean last_party = false;
       mutex.acquire();
       try{
            completed_parties++;
            if (completed_parties == parties){
               last_party = true;
            }
       }finally{
          mutex.release();
       }

       if(last_party){
           waiters.release(parties);
       }
       waiters.acquire();
   }

}
```

Comment: Intresting, looks like it would work however i am being forced to use semaphores.

Comment: I added an update to include how it can be done using a semaphore.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure if you changed your question, or if misunderstood your question. Because currently there is only a group of threads you want to synchronize and not a main thread that needs to wait for a group of threads to complete.

Comment: Yea its only a group of threads and there is no main thread. Also are you suggesting creating a semaphore with negative permits? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. You can create a semaphore with negative permits.

Comment: Who is forcing you to use a semaphore? Because it sounds like making a problem more complicated than needs to be.

Comment: University assignment where i have to use both monitor and semaphore techniques to deal with threads.

Comment: Im gona try implement this it looks like a good solution

Comment: I have added a CyclicBarrier implementation based on Semaphores.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237198/discussion-between-alexander-fraser-and-pveentjer).